# Java/Groovy method to Invoke SOAP Web Service (Version 1.2)

Tags: java, web-services, soap, groovy

I am trying to invoke Web Service (Version 1.2 and dont have a Version 1.1 for this service) using Java/Groovy code. I have tried below options

Using SAAJ

```
String endpointURL = <<endpoint>>
SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();
// Send SOAP Message to SOAP Server
def Request = <<Request XML>>
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(Request.getBytes());
SOAPMessage soapMessage = MessageFactory.newInstance(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_2_PROTOCOL).createMessage(null, is);      
SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(soapMessage, endpointURL)
```

Using Groovy WsLite

```
 def client = new SOAPClient(<<endpoint>>)
 def response = client.send(SOAPVersion.V1_2, <<RequestXML>>)
```

In both cases the I am receivig and error from service indicating version mismatch. Underlying architecture is Oracle Service Bus.

I am able to invoke Web Services which are available with both Versions 1.1 and 1.2 with the same code. I am suspecting that in this case we are able to invoke only Service belonging to version 1.1

Could someone help me understand what is that I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was resolved by adding SOAPAction as mimeheader in case of SOAP version 1.2. I was able to resolve this issue by passing SOAPAction along with the SOAPVersion

In case of SAAJ passed

```
MimeHeaders mimeh = message.getMimeHeaders();
mimeh.addHeader("SOAPAction",<<soapaction>>);
```

In case of Groovy wslite

```
def response = client.send(SOAPVersion.V1_2, SOAPAction: <<soapaction>>,<<RequestXML>>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your underlying oracle service bus might be configured to support only SOAP 1.1 version. Did you change your code to use SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_1_PROTOCOL and try the same.

If this works, your OSB has to be enabled to support both 1.1 and 1.2 soap versions.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Maruthi. Yes I have changed it to Version 1.1 and tried and I receive the same error. From the information I have the OSB is configured to support only 1.2 version. I am able to invoke the service from SoapUI successfully, but not via this code.

Comment: Sure .. Can you check your classpath libs,whether they have a conflict on loading the soapversion 1.2 (what i mean is , is the error happening even before the request hits OSB)